# What is Phytogenetics?

Tags: genetics

What is Phytogenetics? I have searched google without finding a definition. Is it even a defined term? I found it in a reference relating to genetic engineering.

Comment: Have you really googled the term? If I google `phytogenetics`, the first 8 results are 7 definitions and 1 translation.

Comment: @Remi.b it turns out that google results can vary dramatically for each person depending on geographic location, language preference, and other things, especially if you are logged in as well. It's always good to remind people to do a search and include what they did find in their search. I get a few definitions, offers of translations into other languages (Spanish, Turkish), and an advertisement and a prospectus for two different companies. start-up

Answer (score 2):

Phytogenetic is

> adjective
>
> *Botany*
>
> Relating to the origin and evolution of plants.

(Source: [Oxford English Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phytogenetic))

Answer (score 2):

prefix. **Phyto**, or phyt, is defined as **plant**. An example of phyto used as a prefix is in the word phytol, which means an oily alcohol that comes from combining the chlorophyll of plants with other substances and is used to create synthetic vitamins. http://www.yourdictionary.com/phyto

noun. **Genetics**, the study of heredity and the variation of inherited characteristics. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genetics

Try the google machine or visit a local library next time you have trouble with words. It has worked quite well for people in the past!